# Return type of a method

Tags: java, methods

```
public <return type> methodName (ArrayList<ClassName> list){
    *mutate the list given as parameter*
    return list;
}
```

what must I insert as the return type? I have already tried return type as `ArrayList<ClassName>` and it tells me that the method must return something of the type `ArrayList<ClassName>` which I fed to the method as an argument to begin with, so why is it complaining about the return type? What can I do to circumvent this?

Comment: Does your method override a superclass method?

Comment: What's your actual code? I can't tell what the problem is when it is full of placeholders

Comment: i think, your return might be in a condition, like if(something) then return. Is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are mutating the list (and I assume by *mutate* you mean *change the values of the list* and NOT *reassign the list reference to some other object*), it is safe and actually valid to return `void` because *in Java, references to Objects are passed by value*. So any change done to the list instance pointed to by `list` variable will be visible to other methods.

Answer (score 3):

When you design a signature for a method taking a list, you should choose the return type as follows:

- When a new list is created, and the one passed as parameter is unchanged, return the newly created list
- When a list is mutated in place, do not return anything; use `void`.

In your case, the method should be `void`:

```
public void methodName (ArrayList<ClassName> list){
    *mutate the list given as parameter*
    // do not return anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have different paths in your method, each path should return the specified return type.

For example, if you have a return statement,in if part, you should also have a return statement in else part or outside if.

```
public ArrayList<ClassName> methodName(ArrayList<ClassName> list) {
    if(some condition) {
        ........
        ........
        return list;
    }

    ........
    ........
    return list;

}
```

Your exact problem can't be found unless you post your mutation code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return list at the end of your code, the return type of your method should be Array List, because the list has the type of Array List,
If not put the return type as void and do not return anything.

Comment: The return type can be a List also in case of an arrayList. So i disagree with the statement "return type of your method should be Array List"

Answer (score 0):

Use generics:

```
public <T> List<T> myMethod(List<T> myList) {
    return ...;
}
```

Where T is the result type:

```
List<MyClass> myList = myMethod(myParamList);
```